# jQuery .load 2nd html into main html

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am having trouble using the jQuery .load function to load a separate html file into the main html file. The "fincopy" and "finlinks" classes get loaded correctly, but the html file to load into the main page does not get loaded when the "thumb" gets clicked. I really do not know what I am doing wrong...? Below is my relevant code:

```
   Main HTML file:
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Dan Meier/ Designer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Portfolio of Dan Meier">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Freelance, Design, Illustration, Graphics, Website Design, UI, User Interface, Digital Design">
        <meta name="author" content="Dan Meier">

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Typekit -->
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    </head>

    <!--projects link-->
    <div id="projects_container_new">
        <div id="all_projects">
            <div class="col1">
            <div class="thumb" data-url="project_thesis.html" data-num="0">
            <div class="thumb_title"><span class="thumb_client">Published Thesis Work</span><br />Algorithm & Parametric Design</div>
                        <div class="thumb_hover"><div class="view_project">See<br />Work</div></div>
                        <img class="thumb_image" src="images/thesis_cover.jpg">
                    </div></div>

    <!-- Project Details -->
            <div id="project_container"></div>
            <div class="fin">
                fin.
                <div class="fincopy"><span class="finlinks"><span class="finprev">Prev</span></span> &nbsp;| &nbsp;<span class="finlinks"><span class="finclose">Back to Projects</span></span> &nbsp;| &nbsp;<span class="finlinks"><span class="finnext">Next</span></span></div>
            </div>


    CSS code:
    /* -------- Project Details --------- */
    #project_container {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #project {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #project_hero {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 520px;
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url("../images/mejumping.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right top;
    }

    #project_hero .scan {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url("../images/mejumping.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }

    #project_hero .project_title {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1160px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -580px;
        padding: 130px 0 0 40px;
    }

    #info_container {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #info_container2 {
        width: 1160px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 0 0 40px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .project_info {
        width: 400px;
        margin: -30px 0 0 0;
        padding: 27px 40px 0 40px;
        background-color: #e8e8e8;
        overflow: hidden;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .info_col1 {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 70px;
        padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    .info_col2 {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 135px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .info_col3 {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 700px;
        padding: 0 60px 60px 40px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .info_col3 a {
        color: #3cc9c1;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    }

    .info_col3 a:hover {
        color: #3cc9c1;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #3cc9c1;
    }

    .image_container {
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1280px;
        padding: 100px 40px 0 40px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .image_container .imgs {
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .fin {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "kepler-std-display", Georgia, serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 42px;
        color: #808080;
        padding: 100px 0 130px 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .fincopy {
        font-family: "adelle-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #c1c1c1;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .finlinks {
        color: #808080;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    }

    .finlinks:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #3cc9c1;
    }

    .finclose {
    }

    .finnext {
    }

    .finprev {
    }

    <!--project_thesis.html to load into main MAIN HTML page-->
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Dan Meier/ Designer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Portfolio of Dan Meier">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Freelance, Design, Illustration, Graphics, Website Design, UI, User Interface, Digital Design">
        <meta name="author" content="Dan Meier">

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Typekit -->
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>      
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="project_container"><div id="project">
            <div id="project_hero" style="background-image: url(images/myimage.jpg)">
                <div class="project_title"><h1>TeXT,....<br>Hello</h1></div>
                <div class="scan"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="info_container">
                <div class="project_info">
                    <div class="info_col1">
                        <p>text...,,bmgh</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info_col2">
                        <p>Text...<br>text...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="info_col3">
                    <h3>Project Details</h3>
                    <p>Text goes here....</p>
                    <p>my stuff...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image_container">
                <img class="imgs" src="images/image_001.jpg">
                <img class="imgs" src="images/image_002.jpg">
                <img class="imgs" src="images/image_003.jpg">
            </div>
        </div></div>
    </body>
    </html>


   <!--javascript-->
    // THUMB CLICK

        $thumb.click(function() {
            i = $(this).data('num');
            $('#project_container').load($(this).data('url') + ' #project', function() {

                $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({
                    scrollTop: ($('#project_container').offset().top)
                },700,'easeInOutExpo');

                $fin.css('display', 'block');

                $loader.delay(2000).animate({opacity:"0",},"slow", function() {
                    $loadicon.stop(true).animate({top:"60%"},500,'easeOutExpo');
                    $loader.css('display', 'none');
                });
            });

            $loader.css('display', 'block');
            $loadicon.stop(true).animate({top:"50%"},500,'easeOutExpo');
            $loader.animate({opacity:"1",},400,'easeOutCubic');

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javaScript code, there is an extra space in your container name :

```
$('#project_container').load($(this).data('url') + ' #project', function(){
... code
})
```

Just replace `' #project'` by `'#project'` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work...I am loading from my desktop, not hosting the site yet if that matters...?

Comment: I run it from my desktop and it worked fine. Are you sure your other file is in the same directory as the main file and that it is named exactly 'project_thesis.html' ?. Also, in your javaScript code, change `$thumb` to `$('.thumb')` (even if you already declared $thumb somewhere else).